How can we provide feedback to the foundation models that we are using on Bedrock?
We want to implement something similar to ChatGPT console where a user can provide feedback to model generated result. I am using Anthropic's Claude 3, Haiku.
Explored docs, but I didn't get any information on providing feedback to foundation models which we use on Amazon Bedrock

Do you mean adding context, or is the feedback you mention, something different?
